# getResource() is returning null with Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, resources, classpath

I'm aware there are several other questions regarding this...

> - [Class.getResource() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581687/class-getresource-returns-null)
> - [Java - class.getResource returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301329/java-class-getresource-returns-null)
> - [Calling context.getResources() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374027/calling-context-getresources-returns-null)
> - [getClassLoader().getResource(filepath) returns a null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332371/getclassloader-getresourcefilepath-returns-a-null-pointer)

But my problems seems to be a bit different because I seem to have all of the necessary things to NOT have this problem.

**The code:**

```
 this.getClass().getResource("checkstyle_whitespace.xml"); // null
```

The issue is that I've verified my classpath by inspecting the class loader in the debugger. Here's what I am seeing:

```
 27 = {URL@1235} "file:/Users/dennis/Documents/Development/java/java-grader/build/classes/main/"
 28 = {URL@1236} "file:/Users/dennis/Documents/Development/java/java-grader/build/resources/main/"
```

Blow is a quick `tree` of my directory structure. See `build/resources` and `src/main/resources`. The files are being copied when gradle builds my project.

```
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   └── javaGrader
│   │   └── test
│   │       └── javaGraderTest
│   └── resources
│       └── main
│           ├── checkstyle_whitespace.xml
│           └── grammars
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── javaGrader
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── checkstyle_whitespace.xml
│   │       └── grammars
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       │   └── javaGraderTest
│       └── resources
│           └── mini_test
├── target
│   ├── classes
│   ├── generated-sources
│   │   └── annotations
│   └── generated-test-sources
│       └── test-annotations
└── test_assets
```

From what I understand, the files should be accessible because they're in `build`. Correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you pass a resource path that doesn't start with a `/` to `Class.getResource()`, the class loader looks for the resource in the package of the class. Not at the root. Your code should be

```
this.getClass().getResource("/checkstyle_whitespace.xml")
```

or

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("checkstyle_whitespace.xml")
```

Comment: I'm using `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/Configuration.json")`. It was working, but after refreshing the project, it starting returning null.

Comment: getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml") 

and

getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Picture.png") 

both methods worked but if you are using gradle then make sure to put those files (images and xml files) in the resources folder.

Otherwise you may still get the null pointer

Comment: This works, but `checkstyle_whitespace.xml` should be placed in `/resources` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder called "resources" in the same Location that java folder exist in the main folder of the project. and locate all the images and other resources into the "resources" folder. the get those like this

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image.png"));
```